# using FSCrawler to create index in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, fscrawler

I have FSCrawler working on a DEV box where the documents are located on the same server as FSCrawler and ElasticSearch. in the _settings.json file I just set the url to be my document location in the form "D:\MyDocs"

Now I'm moving elasticsearch and fscrawler onto a new server and placing the documents onto a seperate server. How should I format the value for url in my _settings.json file now?

So I have (each are physically different servers) 1. WebServer, 2. Document server, 3. search server

elasticsearch and fscrawler are on server 3.

I could just map a network drive from server 2 to server 3 and then map as above or I could create a website in iis on the webserver pointing to the document server and then just use a http://mydocsite/........,

I dont really want to map a network drive and I dont really want to expose the document server through a site. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to the document server using SSH as indicated in the fscrawler documentation. That'll let you index the files in you document server directly.
You can make the following changes to your settings.json

```
{
  "name" : "test",
  "fs" : {
    "url" : "/path/to/data/dir/on/server"
  },
  "server" : {
    "hostname" : "mynode.mydomain.com",
    "port" : 22,
    "username" : "username",
    "password" : "password",
    "protocol" : "ssh"
  }
}
```